# How to grab indexPath item from a collection view cell for a delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, pushviewcontroller

I have a collectionView that has a section header. In that section header I've added another collectionView that displays recommended profiles for users to follow, and it scrolls horizontal.

I cannot push view controllers from a ReuseableView ( that holds the second collection view), so I created a protocol that will hold a function that can push the view controller for me.

When I tap a profile (cell) it pushes me to my own profile. Because I cannot grab the `indexPath.item` that is in another collectionView.

**Protocol**

- Here I create the protocol that holds the func `HandleProfileTapped` ,the cell named `FeedReuseableView` is the name of the sectionHeader that holds the second collection view.

```swift
protocol PeopleToFollowDelegate {
    func handleProfileTapped(for cell: FeedReusableView)
}
```

**Function to push user**

- Right here is the function I created in the feed file, I will use this function in the delegate for the section header. However this is where my issues start.

```swift
 // Create function to push users to the correct profile when selected
    func handleProfileTapped(for header: FeedReusableView) {

        print("profile tapped, push user to the correct profile page")
       let header = FeedReusableView()

        //try to grab the indexpath item so the corrext data is pushed
        let user = header.peopleToFollow // ??? What goes here? I cannot grab index path

            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

           let profileViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as? ProfileViewController
            profileViewController?.user? = user


            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController!, animated: true)

       }
```

- This is where I get the biggest issue, `peopleToFollow = [User]()` is the recommended profiles users will see in the section header. **IF** the collection view was not in a section header, then I would easily grab the indexPath like this

```swift
// When profile is tapped, push user to userProfile
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let user = peopleToFollow[indexPath.item]
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let profileViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as? ProfileViewController


        profileViewController?.user = user

        // Then push to next controller ( profile)


    }
```

To sum it up, I just need a way to grab the indexPath.item somehow for that func.

**Edit**

Here is also were I use the function in the FeedReuseableView

`var delegate: PeopleToFollowDelegate?`

```swift
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    // Return the number of profiles
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return peopleToFollow.count
    }

    //Display the recommended profiles
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "profilesCell", for: indexPath) as! PeopleToFollowCollectionCell

        cell.user = peopleToFollow[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }

    // When profile is tapped, push user to userProfile
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        profilesTapped()

    }

    @objc func profilesTapped() {
        delegate?.handleProfileTapped(for: self)

      }
```

Comment: why dont you pass it in there 
protocol PeopleToFollowDelegate {
func handleProfileTapped(for cell: FeedReusableView, indexPath:IndexPath)
}

Comment: I don't know how to pass the index path though

Comment: @AbuUlHassan Or I should really say, I'm not sure what to even put in the indexPath code.

Comment: Share the way and where you use your protocol function `handleProfileTapped(: FeedReusableView)`

Comment: @Andrew21111 Done sir

Comment: you can pass index path here in profilesTapped(indexpath: indexPath) {}

Comment: @ShehzadAli sorry a little confused reading code from comment, can you make that an answer?

Comment: @Clint check answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can change the implementation of didSelectRow from

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        profilesTapped()
}
```

to

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        profilesTapped(user: peopleToFollow[indexPath.item])
}
```

Here is the implementation of profilesTapped

```
@objc func profilesTapped(user: User) {
    delegate?.handleProfileTapped(for: user)
}
```

Edited:
For pushing view controller you should do this. Apologies if I typed something wrong as I am using my phone now.

```
func handleProfileTapped(for user: User) {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

    if let profileViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profileViewController") as? ProfileViewController {
    profileViewController.user = user
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Its still sending me to my own profile. Remember the ```didSelect``` is coming from a CollectionViewReuseableView, so I have to create the function ```handleProfilesTapped``` in another file that has a view controller so I can push. However when creating the function I cannot grab the  ```peopleToFollow``` indexPath because I am not writing the code in the ```didSelect``` function of the collectionView

Comment: What do you get if you put a break point in didSelectItemAt indexPath and print user in console like ```po peopleToFollow[indexPath.item]```

Comment: It returns <User: 0x280479a80> which is the first user in the index, which is what I want. However when I select it, I get pushed to my own profile, and not the user in the index I am tapping on

Comment: So you got the right user here. Now put a break point ```@objc func profilesTapped(user: User)``` and you must be getting right user here. After that check the user profile instance to which you are assigning user. Is it getting right value

Comment: Also put a break point in function where you are updating your view with selected user and add another break point when you are assigning this selected user to profieViewController before pushing it. Make sure you are displaying the right user.

Comment: The biggest issue is in the code ```handleProfileTapped``` all I need is to somehow grab that ```indexPath.item``` But I can so its just going to push to my own profile. I've updated the question.

Comment: My biggest question is can you show me how you would push the view controller? Or how you would write the func ```handleProfileTapped```

Comment: You're a wizard Harry! It works thank you. Will award bounty and accept answer.

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Abu Ul Hassan you can pass IndexPath as a argument to your protocol function but after reviewing your code I observed that only thing you need is selected index therefore for simplicity you can do this in following way:

1. Modify your protocol method

   ```
    protocol PeopleToFollowDelegate {
        func handleProfileTapped(forIndex selectedIndex: Int)
    }
   ```
2. Call delegate function from User's collectionView's didSelect delegate

   ```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         peopleToFollowDelegate.handleProfileTapped(forIndex: indexPath.item) 

    }
   ```
3. Then write handleProfileTapped function like this:

   ```
   func handleProfileTapped(forIndex selectedIndex: Int) {

        let user = peopleToFollow[selectedIndex]
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let profileViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"profileViewController") as? ProfileViewController


        profileViewController?.user = user

        // Then push to next controller
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection view delegate didSelectItem inside section header and directly push to profile viewcontroller from section reusable view by accessing topMost viewcontroller in navigation stack by using following code.

```
extension UIApplication {
 class func topVC(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
      return topVC(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
      if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
        return topVC(controller: selected)
      }
    }
    if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
      return topVC(controller: presented)
    }
    return controller
  }
}

extension UIViewController {
  func pushVC(_ vc: UIViewController, animated: Bool = true) {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: animated)
  }
}
```

Use case: UIApplication.topVC()?.pushVC(, animated: true)